# Using sed to pull out datetime

Tags: regex, sed

I am looking at an access log from tomcat which has entires such as:

```
96.28.193.125 - - [10/May/2012:07:08:39 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
```

I want to use sed to just pull out the datetimes.

So I just see:

```
[10/May/2012:07:08:39 +0000]
```

I understand it should be something like this:

```
sed -e 's/oldstuff//g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

Where oldstuff should be a regular expression to get text that is not between square brackets.

I haven't a clue how to express that in a regular expression and would appreciate any tips?

My best effort is:

```
sed -e 's
/[^\[(.*?)\]]//g' inputfilename > outputFileName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  sed -e 's;^.*\(\[.*\]\).*$;\1;' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

Comment: @dublintech: is everything in single line? It works for me. Maybe try with `\1\n` instead of `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o '\[[^]]\+\]' file
```

find a <kbd>[</kbd> then one or more characters that are not <kbd>]</kbd> then a <kbd>]</kbd>